# flux multiple components in same page are influenced with each other, bugs

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am using same component multiple times in the same page, and I just realized that any event dispatched are intercepted by all the same companents and all the components are updated together.
This is not acceptable, as even if it is same component, if it is used to display different data, they should have totally independent behavior. Action performed in one component should never be listened by another component.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: It would probably help if you could explain your setup and flow more clearly: in a typical react-flux setup, `<Component>s` do not intercept dispatched events (only stores do). `Stores` listen to dispatched events, and emit changes. `<Component>s` listen to change emits, possibly fetch data from `Stores`, and re-render. `<Component>s` do not listen to other `<Component>s` (only to stores, and to user interaction).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a container component which will get a data collection, which represents the component you are repeating. An action will change that data collection, and not the repeated component itself. In other words, the repeated component should not get data directly from the store.

You could see an full todomvc example, which has the same "TodoItem" component being rendered a few times in one page here: [TodoMVC example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc)

Example:

```
var ButtonStore = require('../stores/ButtonStore');

function getButtonState() {
  return {
    allButtons: ButtonStore.getAll()      
  }
}

const Button = (props) => {
  return <button>{props.text}</button>
}

class ButtonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = getButtonState()
  }

   render() {  
    return <div>
            {this.state.allButtons.map(button => <Button {...button} />)}
           </div>
  }
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the example, just without the store: [Component List Example](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/4jr8Lfs3/30/)

It could be helpful, if you post some code example.